# Create sequence with order AAB, AA1, AA9, ABA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to create sequence that stored in db.
So just only with one service call I should get new sequence by order like AAB.
Next call should return AAC, next AAD.... AA9, ABA...
I tried to create three number sequences 0<=first_seq<36, also like this second_seq, third_seq.
I am using spring hibernate, postgresql.

Comment: **1.** Can you be more specific about the order of the characters in your sequence? At the moment it looks like `AAA`=0, `AAZ`=24, `AA0`=25, `AA9`=34, `ABA`=35. Or does it not use `0`? Do the letters end at `Z` or `D`? Is it fully custom or is it some well-known [numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system), like [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), and can you change it? **2.** Do you need to store the *sequence* in the database, or the *values* of this sequence? **3.** Do you need a mechanism allowing you to create multiple instances of such sequence?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Well your question is ambiguous, you should indicate wanting a Java or a Postgres solution at a minimum. The following presents a fully generic Postgres solution given only the previous *sequence* and a string with the ordered set of digits. It creates 2 CTEs the first defines a the digits then the second 'builds' a working set of variables. Finally the main sql builds the next sequence. This is handled is a single statement, nested into a sql function. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uj0nIY_r))

```
create or replace function strange_sequence_nextval(current_seq_in text)
     returns text 
    language sql
    immutable
as $$
   with avail_set (k_ent) as ( values('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789') )
      , parms_set (k_ent, k_len, l_pos, l_len, l_val) as 
        (select k_ent
              , length(k_ent) 
              , position(right(current_seq_in, 1) in (k_ent) )
              , length(current_seq_in)
              , left(current_seq_in, length(current_seq_in)-1)
           from avail_set 
        ) 
    select case when current_seq_in is  null then left(k_ent,1) 
                when l_pos = k_len           then concat( strange_sequence_nextval(l_val), left(k_ent,1)) 
                when l_len < 2               then substr( k_ent, l_pos+1, 1)
                else                              concat( l_val, substr( k_ent, l_pos+1, 1)) 
           end
      from parms_set;
$$;
```

NOTE: As a SQL function it can be extracted and run as an independent statement. You will just need to pass the *current sequence* as a parameter.

---

EDIT: Reply to Vérace. I did not get the generate the entire sequence because as stated *Next call should return AAC, next (call) AAD ...*. Further the sequence from `... AA9, ABA...` has no ending. But without reworking the function you could use it within a recursive query.

```
with recursive seq_gen(seq, gen_no, stop_at) as
     ( select 'AAA', 1, 100         -- or any other random point
       union all 
       select strange_sequence_nextval(seq), gen_no+1, stop_at 
         from seq_gen 
        where gen_no < stop_at        
    )
select seq
  from seq_gen;
```

Comment: That's some pretty fancy function there, but my understanding is that the OP want to generate the entire sequence in one go - not one value at a time - how would you call your function to get it to produce more than one value? +1 anyway for the code :-)

Comment: See EDIT section in answer.

Comment: Really nice! Would you care to comment on my code? p.s. there's only one CTE in your answer! Readem and weep - https://dbfiddle.uk/mOjvQTfF :-) But I see now that your question really answers the OP's question in a general sense - mine is more restricted! *Chapeau Monsieur!" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final String DIGITS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
static final int LENGTH = 3;
static int SEED = 0;

public static String nextSequence() {
    int size = DIGITS.length();
    char[] buffer = new char[LENGTH];
    for (int n = ++SEED, i = LENGTH - 1; i >= 0; --i, n /= size)
        buffer[i] = DIGITS.charAt(n % size);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    System.out.println(nextSequence());
```

output

```
AAB
AAC
AAD
AAE
AAF
AAG
AAH
AAI
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I did this (all of the code below is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/M6ub_3cK)).

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING('ABCDE123', s.i, 1) AS c1,
  SUBSTRING('ABCDE123', t.j, 1) AS c2,
  SUBSTRING('ABCDE123', u.k, 1) AS c3
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(1, 8) AS s(i),
  GENERATE_SERIES(1, 8) AS t(j),
  GENERATE_SERIES(1, 8) AS u(k)
ORDER BY c1, c2, c3
LIMIT 10;
```

Result:

```
c1  c2  c3
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   1   3
1   1   A
1   1   B
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

**But**, you want it sorted `AAA`, `AAB`... but `1` is before `A` in the ASCII table, so we have to do this:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT

    SUBSTRING('ABCDE123', s.i, 1) AS c1,
    SUBSTRING('ABCDE123', t.j, 1) AS c2,
    SUBSTRING('ABCDE123', u.k, 1) AS c3
  
  FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, 8) AS s(i),
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, 8) AS t(j),
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, 8) AS u(k)
)
SELECT 
  c1 || c2 || c3 AS sequence
FROM
  cte1
ORDER BY 

  CASE
    WHEN ASCII(c1) < 58 THEN ASCII(c1) + 45 --  45 is arbitrary, as long as it gets
    ELSE ASCII(c1)                          --  (ASCII(c1) + 45 > 90). Check an ASCII table!
  END,
  
  CASE
    WHEN ASCII(c2) < 58 THEN ASCII(c2) + 45
    ELSE ASCII(c2)
  END,
  
  CASE
    WHEN ASCII(c3) < 58 THEN ASCII(c3) + 45
    ELSE ASCII(c3)
  END
LIMIT 10;
```

Result:

```
sequence
AAA
AAB
AAC
AAD
AAE
AA1
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

So, now we have the correct sort order.

We can put all of this in a function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seq(str TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
  WITH cte1 AS
  (
    SELECT

      SUBSTRING($1, s.i, 1) AS c1,
      SUBSTRING($1, t.j, 1) AS c2,
      SUBSTRING($1, u.k, 1) AS c3
  
    FROM
      GENERATE_SERIES(1, LENGTH($1)) AS s(i),
      GENERATE_SERIES(1, LENGTH($1)) AS t(j),
      GENERATE_SERIES(1, LENGTH($1)) AS u(k)  
  )

  SELECT 
    c1 || c2 || c3 AS sequence
  FROM
  cte1
  ORDER BY 

    CASE
      WHEN ASCII(c1) < 58 THEN ASCII(c1) + 45  -- <<= 45 is arbitrary, as long as it gets
      ELSE ASCII(c1)                           --     it above 90. Check an ASCII table!
    END,
  
    CASE
      WHEN ASCII(c2) < 58 THEN ASCII(c2) + 45
      ELSE ASCII(c2)
    END,
  
    CASE
      WHEN ASCII(c3) < 58 THEN ASCII(c3) + 45
      ELSE ASCII(c3)
    END
$$;
```

and the run:

```
SELECT
  seq('ABC1')
  LIMIT 10;
```

Result:

```
seq
AAA
AAB
AAC
AA1
ABA
ABB
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

With thanks to @Belayer's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74168879/470530) for the inspiration on the function!